# Grails redirect to a page in case of error

Tags: grails, redirect

Here is a simple question. Is there any possibility of, if in any case there's an error in an application and the server show us an error page, instead redirect everything to a default page ?

Covering all errors.. is that possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grails already does this for you. If an exception bubbles up to the container, it gets handled as an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error). With `conf/URLMappings.groovy` you can control what happens what happens when error statuses occur.

Here's the default mapping for 500 responses (from `conf/URLMappings.groovy`):

```
"500"(view:'/error')
```

This tells the application to render the `error` view, which is located in `views/error.gsp`. If you want to change this, you can. You could redirect to a controller/action if you want:

```
// will go to 'custom' action of ErrorController, which you would create yourself
"500"(controller: "error", action: "custom")
```

You can configure this for any HTTP response status. See the [URL Mappings documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4.4%20Mapping%20to%20Response%20Codes). If you need finer control over different exceptions that might be encountered, look at the "Declarative Error Handling" section in the referenced docs above.